# Ошибка компиляции Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

```
@Entity
class User (
    @PrimaryKey val deviceId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val password: String
)

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM name")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Insert
    fun insert(user: User)

    @Update
    fun update(user: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}

@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

При компиляции пишет error: There is problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database(no such table: name)

Что делать? Всю голову уже сломал.

Comment: SELECT * FROM name
Почему имя таблицы name если user

Comment: @Jacob блин, точно. Спасибо!